# How to record a live video of yourself with a transparent background?

Tags: editing, greenscreen, live-recording

I always watch and wonder how some youtubers have a little window on a corner of a gameplay or something...

My doubt isn't on how they get the image, my doubt is on how some youtubers get the video of themselves with a transparent background on top of the gameplay.

I know this requires a green screen, but I really want to know how this gets automatically edited. I have seen some live gameplay with the transparent effect.

How do the youtubers get a transparent background on a live feed?

What I am trying to achieve is, recording myself on a live feed, but with a transparent background... If you see what I mean...

Answers much appreciated,

Sid

Comment: can you give us an example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Check the edit, what I am trying to do, is, I am trying to do a live video feed on twitch or something, but the background around be is transparent so I am like an over lay on the corner of the main gameplay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I really want to know how this gets automatically edited.

The technique is called [chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) and consists of considering as transparent all pixels of the colors within a specified range. This is usually used with a bluescreen or a green background. The image is then simply layered over another background.

As you have noticed, chroma key is not limited to postprocessing: [a lot of software products](https://www.google.fr/search?q=chroma%20key%20real-time) can do this in real-time for live streaming.

By the way, if you have used Google Hangouts, [one of the effects](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2013/07/google-effects-for-google-hangouts.html) consists of replacing the background by an image. Don't be mislead by this, since this has nothing to do with a bluescreen and doesn't require any specific color for the background; I imagine that Hangouts' algorithm rather assumes that parts that don't move are the actual background.

Comment: Ah, perfect, chroma key is what I was looking for! Thanks!